# Do I need to create extra CSS classes for that?

Tags: html, css, class, hover

I have a CSS question with this image hover effect - "[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKw2P/1/)". I can't use width 100% in `.img-overlay` to get the overlay to cover the whole areas of the two pictures, so I have to use `width:138px` for the first one and `width:300px` for the second. In doing so, I end up making 4 more classes (`.img-overlay2` `.img-overlay2.2` `.img-overlay2 h4 .img-overlay2 p`, `.img-wrap:hover .img-overlay2`) Is there a more concise way to achieve that? Can I avoid some of the duplication?

CSS

```
.img-wrap{
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}
.img-overlay{
background-color:#8DBDD8;
bottom:0;
color:#222;
opacity:0;
filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
position:absolute;
width:138px;
height:100%;
z-index:1000;
}


.img-overlay h4, .img-overlay p{
padding:0 10px;

}
.img-wrap:hover .img-overlay{
opacity:0.75;
filter: alpha(opacity = 75);
transition:opacity 0.25s;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.25s;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.25s;
}


.img-overlay2{
background-color:#8DBDD8;
bottom:0;
color:#222;
opacity:0;
filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
position:absolute;
width:300px;
height:100%;
z-index:1000;
}

.img-overlay2.2{
width:100%;
}


.img-overlay2 h4, .img-overlay2 p{
padding:0 10px;

}
.img-wrap:hover .img-overlay2{
opacity:0.75;
filter: alpha(opacity = 75);
transition:opacity 0.25s;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.25s;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.25s;
}
```

Comment: your requirement/problem is not so clear... kindly rephrase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep the class names - without changing your markup or CSS much, you can reduce the duplication by defining common attributes once, then overriding specific attributes later in your stylesheet:

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/EKw2P/3/)</kbd>

```
.img-overlay,
.img-overlay2 {
    background-color:#8DBDD8;
    bottom:0;
    color:#222;
    opacity:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position:absolute;
    width:138px;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}

.img-overlay2 {
    width:300px;
}

.img-overlay h4, .img-overlay p,
.img-overlay2 h4, .img-overlay2 p {
    padding:0 10px;
}

.img-wrap:hover .img-overlay,
.img-wrap:hover .img-overlay2 {
    opacity:0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    transition:opacity 0.25s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.25s;
}
```

By adding two additional class definitions and adding them to your overlay elements while removing references to img-overlay2:

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/EKw2P/5/)</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div class="img-overlay small">...
<div class="img-overlay large">...
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.img-overlay {
    background-color:#8DBDD8;
    bottom:0;
    color:#222;
    opacity:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position:absolute;
    width:138px;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}

.img-overlay.small {
    width: 138px;
    height: 159px;
}

.img-overlay.large {
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
}

.img-overlay h4, .img-overlay p {
    padding:0 10px;
}

.img-wrap:hover .img-overlay {
    opacity:0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    transition:opacity 0.25s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.25s;
}
```

If you can apply dimensions on your `img-wrap` element, you could change to something like this:

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/EKw2P/4/)</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div class="img-wrap small">…</div>
<div class="img-wrap large">…</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.img-wrap.small {
    width: 138px;
    height: 159px;
}

.img-wrap.large {
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
}

.img-overlay {
    background-color:#8DBDD8;
    bottom:0;
    color:#222;
    opacity:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use something like this http://jsfiddle.net/EyAdp/

HTML:

```
<div class="a image"><div class="overlay"></div></div>
<div class="b image"><div class="overlay"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
    width:150px;
    height:60px;
    background-image:url("http://placekitten.com/150/60");
}
.b {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-image:url("http://placekitten.com/100/50");
}
.image {
    position:relative;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
}
.overlay:hover {
    background-color:rgba(1,1,1,0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes... you can avoid the duplications easily. see the following approach:

```
.img-wrap{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.img-overlay{
    background-color:#8DBDD8;
    bottom:0;
    color:#222;
    opacity:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}
.img-overlay h4, .img-overlay p{
    padding:0 10px;
}
.img-wrap:hover .img-overlay{
    opacity:0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 75);
    transition:opacity 0.25s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.25s;
}
.img-overlay138{
    width:138px;
}
.img-overlay300{
    width:300px;
}
```

and you html:

```
<div class="img-wrap">
<a href='#'><img src='http://wizzywizzyweb.gmgcdn.com/media/products/payday-2-4-pack/boxart/small-payday-2-4-pack_boxart_tall-136x159.jpg' alt="bbh"/></a><div 
class="img-overlay img-overlay138">
<p>dfdfdf</div></div>

    <div class="img-wrap">
<a href='#'><img src='http://wizzywizzyweb.gmgcdn.com/media/smallofferboxes/2013/09/13/Voucher-Low-offer-box04_.jpg' alt="ddfdf"/></a><div 
class="img-overlay img-overlay300">
<p>dfdfdf
    </div></div>
```